# How to get total of page views for each URL using the new Google Analytics Reports API

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-reporting-api

In the past I used this code for get the total of views of each URL:

```
$optParams = array(
    'max-results' => 9999,
    'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
    'sort' => 'ga:pagePath,ga:pageviews',
    'start-index'=>1,
);

$res= $analytics->data_ga->get(
    'ga:' . $profileId,
    '2011-01-01',
    'today',
    'ga:pageviews',
    $optParams);
    $rows=$res["rows"];

 print_r($rows);
```

But I discover issues in the old Google Analytics API. I reported this issue at Github where [they advised me to use the new Reporting API](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1772#issuecomment-578306266) .

I test some examples from the API documentation, but I cannot get the total visits for each page as I did with the old API.

How I can achieve this?

I'm implementing this code:

```
function getReport($analytics) {

  // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
  $VIEW_ID = "XXXXXXXX";

  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("2013-01-01");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:pageviews");
  $sessions->setAlias("pageviews");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));
//var_dump($request);
  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}
```

This return the total global of views into the site, but I want to get the total of views for each page.

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what the problem is with your code?  Is there an error? That code

Comment: @DaImTo I added the code at end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a ga:pagePath dimension.

```
// Create the DateRange object.
$dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$dateRange->setStartDate("2011-01-01");
$dateRange->setEndDate("today");

// Create the Metrics object.
$sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$sessions->setExpression("ga:pageviews");
$sessions->setAlias("pageviews");

//Create the Dimensions object.
$pagePath = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$pagePath->setName("ga:pagePath");

// Create the ReportRequest object.
$request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
$request->setViewId("XXXX");
$request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
$request->setDimensions(array($pagePath));
$request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

$body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
$body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
return $analyticsreporting->reports->batchGet( $body );
```

Comment: Thanks. With this code I'm getting multiple results as: `[dimensions] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => /?s=leccionario+biblico+patristico+ciclo+bienal
                                                )` but this is not the URL `/?s=leccionario+biblico+patristico+ciclo+bienal`. And is nothing about the total of views for the URL.